# Mutually dependent type declarations and Ada.Containers

Tags: ada, recursive-datastructures

In an implementation of "boxed types" (for an interpreter) I originally had vectors in a child package and used System.Access_To_Address_Conversions to convert from System.Address to Vector_Ptr as needed in order to avoid seemingly insurmountable problems with cyclic dependencies. (At least, no use of limited with every did the trick for me.) It worked but seemed like a nasty hack. So I've decided to put the container types into the main package Types.Boxed. Now GNAT complains 'no declaration in visible part for incomplete type "Vector" defined at line 12'

Is there any way to fix this? Or should I return to my nasty hack?

Ada 2005 using GNAT 4.6 with flag -gnat05

```
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with Ada.Strings.Wide_Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Wide_Unbounded;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Green_Tasks; use Green_Tasks;

package Types.Boxed is

   type Type_T is (T_Null, T_Unsigned_64, T_String, T_Boolean,
                   T_Green_Task, T_Vector);

   type String_Ptr is access all Unbounded_Wide_String;
   type Vector;
   type Vector_Ptr is access all Vector;

     type Item (IType : Type_T := T_Null) is record
        case IType is
        when T_Null        => null;
        when T_Unsigned_64 => Value_Unsigned_64  : Unsigned_64;
        when T_String      => Value_String       : String_Ptr;
        when T_Boolean     => Value_Boolean      : Boolean;
        when T_Green_Task  => Value_Green_Task   : Green_Task_Ptr;
        when T_Vector      => Value_Vector       : Vector_Ptr;
        end case;
   end record;

   procedure Free (Datum : in out Item);
   procedure Box (Datum : out Item; Value : in Unsigned_64);
   function Unbox (Datum : Item) return Unsigned_64;
   procedure Box (Datum : out Item; Value : String_Ptr);
   function Unbox (Datum : Item) return String_Ptr;
   procedure Box (Datum : out Item; Value : in Boolean);
   function Unbox (Datum : Item) return Boolean;
   procedure Box (Datum : out Item; Value : in Green_Task_Ptr);
   function Unbox (Datum : Item) return Green_Task_Ptr;
   function Get_Boxed_Type (Datum : Item) return Type_T;

   -- vectors
    package Item_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
     ( Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => Item
     );
   use Item_Vectors;


   function Vector_New (Size_Hint : Positive) return Item;
   function Unbox (Datum : Item) return Vector_Ptr;
   procedure Vector_Free (V : in out Vector_Ptr);
   function Vector_Copy (V : Vector_Ptr) return Item;

   pragma Inline (Box);
   pragma Inline (Unbox);
   pragma Pure_Function (Unbox);
   pragma Pure_Function (Get_Boxed_Type);


end Types.Boxed;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I assume that you thought when you instantiated `Item_Vectors` and said `use Item_Vectors`, that the `Vector` type in `Item_Vectors` would be the completion of the incomplete `Vector` you wrote earlier.

It doesn't.  When you say `use P`, it means that all the names defined in `P` are now directly visible, so if `P` declares a type `T`, you can say `T` instead of saying `P.T`.  **But the symbols still belong to P.**  They do not become "part of" the package that contains the `use`.  Thus, for instance, `use Item_Vectors;` means that you can say `Empty_Cursor` instead of `Item_Vectors.Empty_Cursor`.  But there will **not** be a `Types.Boxed.Empty_Cursor`.  The name still belongs to `Item_Vectors`.

What this means is that when you have an incomplete `Vector` type in `Types.Boxed`, there needs to be a completion **in** `Types.Boxed`.  The `Vector` type in `Item_Vectors` does not become the completion of the type, and the `use` doesn't help with that.

Unfortunately, Ada doesn't let you complete the type with a "type rename" or a `subtype`.  The best option I can think of is

```
type Vector is new Item_Vectors.Vector with null record;
```

Note that this causes all the operations in `Item_Vector` to be inherited for `Vector`.  So this might work for you.  But there could be some unanticipated problems.  But I can't think of a better solution.

**EDIT:** It looks like Simon has a good possible solution.

Comment: The trouble with extending any of the Containers is the number of functions that return a value of the container type (Vector has 7) and which therefore have to be overridden.

Comment: @SimonWright No, as of Ada 2005, functions don't have to be overridden when the type extension is a _null extension_.

Comment: O yes, I remember now that the point of *my* attempt on those lines was for the extension to have additional content. Oops.

Comment: Both solutions work. I've chosen this solution, because I didn't want to add another layer of indirection, and GNAT has swallowed it after I have resolved a few ambiguities elsewhere. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this and found that I could get it to compile by making `Item_Vectors` of element type `Item_Ptr`:

```
type Item (<>);
type Item_Ptr is access all Item;

package Item_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
 ( Index_Type   => Natural,
   Element_Type => Item_Ptr
  );
subtype Vector is Item_Vectors.Vector;
type Vector_Ptr is access all Vector;

type Item (IType : Type_T := T_Null) is record
   case IType is
      when T_Null        => null;
      when T_Unsigned_64 => Value_Unsigned_64  : Unsigned_64;
      when T_String      => Value_String       : String_Ptr;
      when T_Boolean     => Value_Boolean      : Boolean;
      when T_Vector      => Value_Vector       : Vector_Ptr;
     end case;
end record;
```

(I removed `Green_Tasks`, hopefully not relevant to your problem).

I was interested to see from [ARM 3.10.1(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10-1.html#p3) that the complete declaration can only be postponed to the body if the incomplete declaration is in the private part.